# MobX - Why should I use `observer` when I could use `inject` when injecting data into a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobx, mobx-react

MobX documentation suggests I should use `observer` on all my components. However by using inject I get more fine grained control over what data causes a re-rendering of my components.

My understanding is I that with `observer`, a change in all accessed observables in the last render will cause a re-render, even if the observable is nested deep in the data store, while `inject` only re-renders when observables accessed in the injector function change.

For example:

```
class Store{
  @observable data = {
    nestedData: {
      deepData: 'my_data'
    }
  }
}

const store = new Store();

... Assume the store is injected using <Provider /> component

// This will cause re-render when the data object changes
// for example: store.data = { new_data: 'new_data' }
@inject(stores => {
  return { data: stores.dataStore.data }; 
})
class MyComponent extends Component {  }

// This will re-render on change of the data object, but also
// on change of nestedData and deepData properties
@inject(stores => {
  return { data: stores.dataStore.data }; 
})
@observer
class MyComponent extends Component {  }
```

Could someone confirm my understanding of this?

In my opinion, it's better to use only `inject` as it gives you more control, and can prevent unnecessary re-renders. If the data is deeply nested you could create a computed property that gets and prepares the data from the deep structure and then inject that property in the component.

Are there other benefits/drawbacks when using one over the other

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you are correct in your assessment. Let me try to rephrase for clarity:

[`@observer`](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react#observercomponentclass) tracks which observables are used by `render` and automatically re-renders the component when one of these values changes.

We should note that `@observable` values used by `render` might be deeply nested within a given `prop`, per your example:

```
class Store{
  @observable data = {
    nestedData: {
      // changes to `deepData` would theoretically re-render any observer
      deepData: 'my_data' 
    }
  }
}
```

> with observer, a change in all accessed
>   observables in the last render will cause a re-render, even if the
>   observable is nested deep in the data store

**Bingo!**

Although there's a quirk with `observable`, as you'll see in a moment...

---

On the other hand you have [`@inject`](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react#provider-and-inject) which makes available to a component (via `props`) specific data structures defined by a `Provider`.

For example:

```
@inject('title')
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<div>{this.props.title}</div>);
    }
}

const Container = () => (
    <Provider title="This value is passed as a prop using `inject`">
        <MyComponent />
    </Provider>
);
```

> inject only
>   re-renders when observables accessed in the injector function change.

**Bingo!**

`inject` will only spawn a re-render if the `prop` itself has recognized changes.

---

This is effectively the same issue with [shouldComponentUpdate()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) and a deep-comparison of `props` -- though `observer` seems to be [far more efficient](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react#about-shouldcomponentupdate) than `shouldComponentUpdate`.

> In my opinion, it's better to use only inject as it gives you more
>   control, and can prevent unnecessary re-renders.

I wouldn't necessarily go that far... it all depends on how you have your code structured.

If I modify your original example as so:

```
class Store{
    @observable data = {
        nestedData: {}
    };

    constructor() {
        this.data.nestedData.deepData = 'my_data';
    }
}
```

...the addition of `deepData` won't actually get picked up as an observable change (i.e. re-render) because that property didn't exist when we originally tagged `data` as an observable value. So that's one problem.

A different approach could be to do something like this:

```
class Person {
    @observable name = 'John Doe';
}

class Store{
    @observable data = null;

    constructor() {
        this.data = new Person();
    }
}
```

This allows you to spread the observable values out across classes -- so you might still want to inject `Store` into a component (to access `Store.data` but ultimately any observable changes come from updating `Person`.

Comment: "the addition of deepData won't actually get picked up as an observable change" - This is mentioned in Mobx documentation. They recommend using the Map structure if you need to react to adding properties to an object.

Comment: Guys please see my question too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48528283/undefined-is-not-a-function-evaluating-decoratortarget-property-desc
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### 2019+

As of 2019, the @inject method is deprecated. See this article for more details: https://mobx-react.js.org/recipes-inject